# How to generate algebraic data types in scala using scalaPB

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I want to generate below algebraic data types in scala using scalaPB.

```scala
trait MyEventCmd
case class MyEvent(mytype: Int, cp: Option[Double], value: Option[String] = None, id: Option[String] = None) extends MyEventCmd
case object Flush extends MyEventCmd
```

I've defined below protobuf `myevent.proto`-

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message MyEventCmd {
  oneof sealed_value {
    Flush lit = 1;
    MyEvent event = 2;
  }
}

message Flush {
}

message MyEvent {
  int32 eType = 1;
  double cp = 2;
  string value = 3;
  string id = 4;
}
```

The problem with my definition is that `Flush` is generated as `case class` not `case object`.

Also, I don't know how to make field optional and with default value.

Answer (score 0):

ScalaPB generates case classes even when there are no fields. There is no option available to generate case objects.

You can disable default values for all fields in a file (or a package) by setting `no_default_values_in_constructor`. See: https://scalapb.github.io/customizations.html#file-level-options